# How to safely store a unique client id for websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I need to be able to know which client is sending a request to the server through web-sockets and tell it apart from other clients. The solution is a client id but I don't know the best way to store it so that the client can send it along with every request.

client

```
var clientId = null;

if (response.method === "connect"){
    clientId = response.clientId
}
```

Comment: You could generate a random id on the server and send it to the client whenever a connection has been made. Then the server knows the id and the client can send it with every data transfer.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thats what I'm currently doing my problem is storing the ID so the user can't edit it

Comment: In what way can they edit it currently? Please include the code that you want a solution for. That way we can see your current state and what can be improved to help your case.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Updated for code, I am currently just using a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your code with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which remove the possibility to access variables in the global scope outside of the IIFE. So only the code that runs inside of this IIFE can access the `clientId` variable. But changing the `clientId` from, for example, the console wouldn't change a thing.

```
(function() {

  // Put all of your code in this scope.

  var clientId = null;

  if (response.method === "connect"){
    clientId = response.clientId
  }

})();
```

If only overwriting the variable is a problem, then you could alternatively use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to save the id in the browser, either permanently or until the tab has been closed. So you could store it like in the example below.

```
if (response.method === "connect"){
  sessionStorage.setItem('clientId', JSON.stringify(response.clientId));
}
```

And use clientId further down the script, or even in another script on the same page with the following lines:

```
var storedClientId = sessionStorage.getItem('clientId');
if (storedClientId !== null) { // Check if the id has been set.
  var clientId = JSON.parse(storedClientId);
}
```

So the IIFE will make modification to your variables impossible outside of its own scope. And the Web Storage API will store your client id in the browser and not in a variable.

Comment: I have tried both of these however for the first I need to be able to access outside the scope and for the send I can still just change the storage from the developer console.

Comment: The IIFE should be wrapped around the *entire* code in your script; `(function() { // all of your script })()`. And for the storage, yes it will still be changeable because, you know, it's the client.